# Can an app be installed from a link within an SMS?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to launch the app store directly on the device and seed it with an application name, or to launch safari with a link to the app store, from a link within an SMS?

I've been experimenting with putting links such as this into an SMS:

itml://itunes/com/app

or

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8

But I get cannot connect to app store error messages when you click on the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8
```

Comment: Tried that, and itms-apps://itunes.apple.com and item-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ - the app store app launches but then a couple of seconds later displays "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". If I launch the app store app manually its ok.

Comment: @Aminoacids This is because previous link also selected the US store. I've fixed that now. try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure this with the following 2 apps.

http://linksense.io incase your app is multiplatform.

As well, there's http://linktexting.com

If you don't have the engineering resources, these will be useful.